# Input not compatible

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I am training the dataset for Amazon fine foods review. The code that I have written for it is showing an error as-
Encoder_Decoder LSTM...
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:66: UserWarning: Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API: `LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)`
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:67: UserWarning: Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API: `LSTM(10, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, dropo

Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=1

Which part of the code exactly is it telling the error in?

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.
!pip install pyrouge

import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
import logging

from pyrouge.Rouge155 import Rouge155 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras import backend as k
k.set_learning_phase(1)
from keras import initializers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Input,Activation,Add,TimeDistributed,\
Permute,Flatten,RepeatVector,merge,Lambda,Multiply,Reshape
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',\
    level=logging.INFO)

#model parameters
batch_size = 50
num_classes = 1
epochs = 20
hidden_units = 10
learning_rate = 0.005
clip_norm = 2.0

train_data=pd.read_csv("../input/Text Summarization Dataset.csv")

en_shape=np.shape(train_data["Text"][0])
de_shape=np.shape(train_data["Summary"][0])

#Helper Functions    

def encoder_decoder(data):
    print('Encoder_Decoder LSTM...')

    #Encoder
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=en_shape)

    encoder_LSTM = LSTM(hidden_units,dropout_U=0.2,dropout_W=0.2,return_sequences=True,return_state=True)
    encoder_LSTM_rev=LSTM(hidden_units,return_state=True,return_sequences=True,dropout_U=0.05,dropout_W=0.05,go_backwards=True)

    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_LSTM(encoder_inputs)
    encoder_outputsR, state_hR, state_cR = encoder_LSTM_rev(encoder_inputs)

    state_hfinal=Add()([state_h,state_hR])
    state_cfinal=Add()([state_c,state_cR])
    encoder_outputs_final = Add()([encoder_outputs,encoder_outputsR])

    encoder_states = [state_hfinal,state_cfinal]

    #decoder
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,de_shape[1]))
    decoder_LSTM = LSTM(hidden_units,return_sequences=True,dropout_U=0.2,dropout_W=0.2,return_state=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_LSTM(decoder_inputs,initial_state=encoder_states)

    #Pull out XGBoost, (I mean attention)
    attention = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation = 'tanh'))(encoder_outputs_final)
    attention = Flatten()(attention)
    attention = Multiply()([decoder_outputs, attention])
    attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
    attention = Permute([2, 1])(attention)

    decoder_dense = Dense(de_shape[1],activation='softmax')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(attention)
    m
    model= Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_outputs)
    print(model.summary())

    rmsprop = RMSprop(lr=learning_rate,clipnorm=clip_norm)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=rmsprop,metrics=['accuracy'])

    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=tts(data["Text"],data["Summary"],test_size=0.20)
    history= model.fit(x=[x_train,y_train],
              y=y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epochs,
              verbose=1,
              validation_data=([x_test,y_test], y_test))
    print(model.summary())
    #inference mode
    encoder_model_inf = Model(encoder_inputs,encoder_states)

    decoder_state_input_H = Input(shape=(en_shape[0],))
    decoder_state_input_C = Input(shape=(en_shape[0],)) 
    decoder_state_inputs = [decoder_state_input_H, decoder_state_input_C]
    decoder_outputs, decoder_state_h, decoder_state_c = decoder_LSTM(decoder_inputs,
                                                                     initial_state=decoder_state_inputs)
    decoder_states = [decoder_state_h, decoder_state_c]
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

    decoder_model_inf= Model([decoder_inputs]+decoder_state_inputs,
                         [decoder_outputs]+decoder_states)

    scores = model.evaluate([x_test,y_test],y_test, verbose=1)

    print('LSTM test scores:', scores)
    print('\007')
    print(model.summary())
    return model,encoder_model_inf,decoder_model_inf,history


#generate summary from vectors


def generateText(SentOfVecs):
    SentOfVecs=np.reshape(SentOfVecs,de_shape)
    kk=""
    for k in SentOfVecs:
        kk = kk + label_encoder.inverse_transform([argmax(k)])[0].strip()+" "
        #kk=kk+((getWord(k)[0]+" ") if getWord(k)[1]>0.01 else "")
    return kk

"""generate summary vectors"""

def summarize(article):
    stop_pred = False
    article =  np.reshape(article,(1,en_shape[0],en_shape[1]))
    #get initial h and c values from encoder
    init_state_val = encoder.predict(article)
    target_seq = np.zeros((1,1,de_shape[1]))
    #target_seq =np.reshape(train_data['summaries'][k][0],(1,1,de_shape[1]))
    generated_summary=[]
    while not stop_pred:
        decoder_out,decoder_h,decoder_c= decoder.predict(x=[target_seq]+init_state_val)
        generated_summary.append(decoder_out)
        init_state_val= [decoder_h,decoder_c]
        #get most similar word and put in line to be input in next timestep
        #target_seq=np.reshape(model.wv[getWord(decoder_out)[0]],(1,1,emb_size_all))
        target_seq=np.reshape(decoder_out,(1,1,de_shape[1]))
        if len(generated_summary)== de_shape[0]:
            stop_pred=True
            break
    return generated_summary

#Plot training curves

def plot_training(history):
    print(history.history.keys())
    #  "Accuracy"
    plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    # "Loss"
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

def saveModels():
    trained_model.save("%sinit_model"%modelLocation)
    encoder.save("%sencoder"%modelLocation)
    decoder.save("%sdecoder"%modelLocation)

def evaluate_summ(article):
    ref=''
    for k in wt(data['Summary'][article])[:20]:
        ref=ref+' '+k
    gen_sum = generateText(summarize(train_data["Text"][article]))
    print("-----------------------------------------------------")
    print("Original summary")
    print(ref)
    print("-----------------------------------------------------")
    print("Generated summary")
    print(gen_sum)
    print("-----------------------------------------------------")
    rouge = Rouge155()
    score = rouge.score_summary(ref, gen_sum)
    print("Rouge1 Score: ", score)

#Train model and test

trained_model,encoder,decoder,history = encoder_decoder(train_data)
plot_training(history)
evaluate_summ(10)

print(generateText(summarize(train_data["article"][8])))
print(data["Summary"][8])
print(data["Text"][78])
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally in the traceback you obtain after the error you get will guide you to the error's origin (line of code). And the traceback is usually sequential by depth, i.e. the last one corresponds the most shallow call that gave the error. Normally the most shallow call in you case should be line 198 `trained_model,encoder,decoder,history = encoder_decoder(train_data)`.

I would check the input data shapes. The error states it's expecting a certain input dimension of 3 and it received a dimension of 1

I see you're using Spyder, use the debugger to follow up the error to its origin.